# ASP.NET - SelectedValue/Index in Listbox always changing after a postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been wrestling with this problem for days and so far I haven't been able to find an answer that fits this specific issue. Here's the code to load the list in the PageLoad():

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {                
                lstEmprendimientos.DataSource = Emprendimiento.DevolverEmprendimientosConEvaluacionesIncompletas();
                lstEmprendimientos.DataValueField = "id";
                lstEmprendimientos.DataTextField = "titulo";
                lstEmprendimientos.DataBind();
                pnlEvaluador.Visible = false;       
            }
        }
```

The first method loads a list made up of 'Emprendimiento' objects, and on that list's SelectedIndexChanged I call another method to load a list through a method that uses the SelectedValue of the item selected.

My problem is that, no matter what I do, the SelectedIndex is always reset to 0 after a postback, so I can't load the second list using the SelectedValue properly. I've worked with lists for a long while now and I've never had this problem, so it's really baffling. I'd appreciate some help with this.

**Here's the code for the whole page:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {                
            ddlEmprendimientos.DataSource = Emprendimiento.DevolverEmprendimientosConEvaluacionesIncompletas();
            ddlEmprendimientos.DataValueField = "id";
            ddlEmprendimientos.DataTextField = "titulo";
            ddlEmprendimientos.DataBind();
            pnlEvaluador.Visible = false;       
        }
    }

    protected void lstEmprendimientos_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void lstEvaluadores_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Evaluador ev = Evaluador.FindByID(lstEvaluadores.SelectedValue);
    }

    protected void btnAsignarEvaluador_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Emprendimiento emp = Emprendimiento.FindByID(Convert.ToInt32(ddlEmprendimientos.SelectedValue));
        Evaluador ev = Evaluador.FindByID(lstEvaluadores.SelectedValue);
        Evaluacion eva = new Evaluacion(emp, ev, 0, "justificacion", DateTime.Now, false);
        if (eva != null)
        {
            if (eva.Insertar())
            {
                lblFeedback.Text = "Alta exitosa.";
                emp.listaEvaluaciones.Add(eva);
                lstEvaluadores.DataSource = emp.DevolverListaEvaluadoresQueNoEvaluanEmprendimiento();
                lstEvaluadores.DataTextField = "Nombre";
                lstEvaluadores.DataValueField = "Email";
                lstEvaluadores.DataBind();
                pnlEvaluador.Visible = true;
                CargarEvaluadores();
            }
            else
            {
                lblFeedback.Text = "Error en el ingreso de datos.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblFeedback.Text = "Error en el ingreso de datos.";
        }
    }

    protected void btnSeleccionarEmp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         CargarEvaluadores();
    }

    private void CargarEvaluadores()
    {
        Emprendimiento emp = Emprendimiento.FindByID(Convert.ToInt32(ddlEmprendimientos.SelectedIndex));
        lstEvaluadores.DataSource = emp.DevolverListaEvaluadoresQueNoEvaluanEmprendimiento();
        lstEvaluadores.DataTextField = "Nombre";
        lstEvaluadores.DataValueField = "Email";
        lstEvaluadores.DataBind();
        pnlEvaluador.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void ddlEmprendimientos_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CargarEvaluadores();
    }
```

**Page markup:**

<%Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="asignarEvaluador.aspx.cs" Inherits="InterfazUsuario.asignarEvaluador">

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmprendimientos" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlEmprendimientos_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSeleccionarEmp" runat="server" OnClick="btnSeleccionarEmp_Click" Text="Seleccionar emprendimiento" Width="195px" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlEvaluador" runat="server">
    <asp:ListBox ID="lstEvaluadores" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstEvaluadores_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAsignarEvaluador" runat="server" OnClick="btnAsignarEvaluador_Click" Text="Asignar evaluador" Width="135px" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblFeedback" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire ASPX markup for this page ?

Comment: Are you getting correct value in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handlers or in the `click` event or none of the event returning correct value to you ?

Comment: None of them are returning the correct value. I tried calling creating a variable equaling SelectedValue at every step of the way (PageLoad(), SelectIndexChanged()) and it's always 0.

Comment: @Seany84 Sorry, I just added the markup on the main post. I didn't find anything strange on it, but mabye someone else will spot something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your DropDownList and ListBox controls to `AutoPostback`

**DropDownList**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmprendimientos" runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlEmprendimientos_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**ListBox**

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstEvaluadores" runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstEvaluadores_SelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:ListBox>
```

AutoPostBack:

> Set this property to **true** if the server needs to capture the selection
> as soon as it is made. For example, other controls on the Web page can
> be automatically filled depending on the user's selection from a list
> control.
>
> This property can be used to allow automatic population of other controls on > the Web page based on a user's selection from a list.
>
> The value of this property is stored in view state.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, I had both listboxes on AutoPostBack = true before and I switched to a button in a random attempt to make it work. Neither works, sadly.

Comment: @JimWind you need the `AutoPostBack` property set to `true` on both of those controls. Can you put that back or else if will not work anyway.

Comment: Got them both on true, it's still not working. I'm half tempted to email Microsoft asking them if it's a VisualStudio bug or something.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after checking everything out again.

The DataValueField in the list was 'id', and the id field in the 'Emprendimiento' class wasn't defined, so it was always returning a null int (0). Thank you kindly for the help, it was just a dumb mistake in the end.

Comment: Quick, cancel that email to Microsoft :)